# How to create border with half circular shape on one side

Tags: css, css-shapes

Let's say I have a header tag like `<h1>Menu</h1>`

And I want to create a css rule to style it. First, with a blue background color. Then, near the lower right corner of the banner, I want it to style like the image below. Wondering how I can achieve that look.

This is the border style I want to achieve: [Border style wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjdpJ.png)

Seems really hard to achieve with css. Is there an easier way? I don't want it to be an image.

Comment: It's gonna be very hard with pure css, maybe with the `::after` pseude element and some super hacky styling. I personally think you're better of just using an svg or an img *(svg > img in that usecase)*

Comment: "*Seems really hard to achieve with css. Is there an easier way?*" - I appreciate that it probably will be at least difficult to achieve that with CSS, but how far did you get? Where did you get stuck? Also, if that's the title, where/how does the text fit into that shape?

Comment: @PatrickCerny not at all. Easily doable with 1 or 2 pseudo-elements and clip-path

Comment: @tacoshy Yea, you're didn't think about `clip-path` in that example!

Comment: [Boredom set in this evening](https://codepen.io/jsbutler483/pen/VwgLYLo). Not fully tested, and animation only for the example. Note that an image **cannot** be displayed in the blue section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create this with a `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements + a `mask` for the "hole".
Somehow:

```css
.menu {
  --d: 30px;
  --background: blue;
  --padding-bottom: calc(2 * var(--d));
  min-height: calc(3 * var(--d));
  padding-bottom: var(--padding-bottom);
  background: var(--background) content-box;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(var(--d) at calc(4 * var(--d)) calc(100% - var(--padding-bottom)), #0000 98%, red);
          mask: radial-gradient(var(--d) at calc(4 * var(--d)) calc(100% - var(--padding-bottom)), #0000 98%, red);
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.menu:before,
.menu:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  top: calc(100% - var(--padding-bottom));
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu:before {
  left: calc(2 * var(--d));
  background: var(--background);
  width: var(--d);
}

.menu:after {
  left: calc(5 * var(--d));
  width: calc(4 * var(--d));
  border: solid var(--d) var(--background);
}

/* This is just for demonstration */
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(orange, yellow);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it can be done using HTML and CSS.

```css
.car {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.wheel {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.small_wheel {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.wheel.right {
  border: 30px solid blue;
  top: 44px;
  left: 150px;
  background: transparent;
}

.left {
  top: 65px;
  left: 70px;
}

.small_wheel_left {
  background-color: blue;
  top: 65px;
  left: 170px;
  top: 95px;
  left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="car"></div>
<div class="wheel right"></div>
<div class="wheel left"></div>
<div class="small_wheel small_wheel_left"></div>
```

Comment: Very nice, this works with multiple html elements. Not exactly the solution I was looking for since it requires adding extra elements.

Comment: instead of using multiple object you can use ::before and ::after to get the desired result

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution is adding spans, with an absolute positioning, and style each of them to match a simple form in the final result.

note: Don't forget to create a blue background for the h1 tag, and add the spans above that.

For example, for the most left small half circle, you might want to make a blue circle, and place it with its center aligning with the bottom line of the h1 background.

It will take some time, so I recommend to still consider an image.

Comment: Far too broad as an answer. merely acceptable as a comment (note that missing reputation is not an excuse to misuse the answer option to bypass your account limitations). Border radius is not the right tool here. Either SVG, pseudo-elements, and/or `clip-path`. a span is certainly the wrong container to add a block-level pseudo-element.